# Popup to allow autoplay for series of videos

Tags: javascript, autoplay

I would like to play a number of videos in a row (about 1.5 minutes each) for a full experience on my site, but I must mute each one because of the autoplay policy.  Can I display a popup at the beginning of the experience and then if the user confirms, set something so that I can autoplay the next n videos during that session without the user having to un-mute each one?

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to just make a confirm prompt (or preferably a custom confirmation prompt) and if the user says yes then toggle the muted attribute.

Comment: Whose autoplay policy? The browser's? The user's? Yours?

Comment: all modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I want one confirm, for multiple videos.  With the above solution, I would have to put up the pop up for every video.  That is no different than just un-muting for every video.

Comment: (Sorry Im late) No, you would at the start ask the user if they want to unmute all. Then if they say yes unmute every video.